# How to unload the DLL so that does not block a file on a disk?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, dllimport, dll-injection

I have DLL which reads and writes some text files. My main program writes a text file named `Parameters.txt` as an input data for DLL. I use `LoadLibrarу()` function to link DLL with my main program at the run time. After a function call from DLL, which reads `Parameters.txt` file and produce some output, I use `FreeLibrary()` function to unload DLL.

The problem is that after unloading DLL it still blocks `Parameters.txt` for further editing or removing.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

// create Parameters.txt input data file
create_parameters_file(file_path, /*... some stuff to write in file ... */);

// function pointer alias
using FuncPtr = void (*)();
    
HINSTANCE hDLL;
// DLL function pointer
FuncPtr composition_func_ptr;

// load DLL
hDLL = LoadLibrary(dll_path);
if (!hDLL) return -1;
// getting function by name
composition_func_ptr = (FuncPtr)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hDLL, "Composition");
if (!elements_in_system_func_ptr || !composition_func_ptr)  return -1;

// calling DLL function. It reads Parameters.txt and create some output text file 
composition_func_ptr();

// unload DLL
FreeLibrary(hDLL);

// create Parameters.txt input data file AGAIN
create_parameters_file(file_path, /*... some OTHER stuff to write in file ... */);

return 0;
}
```

And this is how `create_parameters_file()` looks like:

```cpp
void create_parameters_file(const std::string& file_path, /* stuff to write */)
{
bool file_opened = true;
std::ofstream out_file(file_path);
file_opened = out_file.is_open(); // this returns FALSE after DLL function call
out_file << ...
out_file.close();
}
```

Is there any way to unload DLL completely so it cannot block the file?

Comment: Unloading a dll doesn't free any resources created by that dll (unless the dll is programmed to do so). You need to fix `composition_func_ptr()` to make it properly close the file

Comment: @AlanBirtles but if I have no DLL source file?

Comment: Contact the developer of the DLL and ask them for help. Why do you imagine that we can help with this DLL?

Comment: Open file handles are process-wide resources.  The only way to make this work without making changes to the DLL is to load the DLL into a child process, and exit/recreate the child process when you want to cleanup the file handles which the DLL leaked.  Lucky for you the data transfer is already using files, so you may avoid having to learn IPC (interprocess communications).

Comment: @BenVoigt I have tried to load DLL inside a `std::thread()` via passing function which loaded and unloaded DLL, while my main thread was waiting for sub thread to finish its function. But no success.

Comment: @ThisIsMayhem A `std::thread` is not a separate process.  Exiting a thread does not cause the OS to cleanup the process's open file handles.  You need to exit a process to do that.

Comment: @BenVoigt would you please share a link where I can find info about creation/recreation so called child process?

Comment: I mean call `CreateProcess` again making a new child process.  The OS doesn't track any relationship between one process ending and a new one started by the same parent.  "Replace" or "Recreate" is only valid in our mental abstraction.

Comment: @ThisIsMayhem could you please answer yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I circumvented the problem by calling an auxiliary application via `CreateProcess()` and loading DLL there. Looks cumbersome, but makes work buggy DLL.